# Running multiple bibliographies with TexnicCenter

Tags: package

I am using a couple of files letters.bib and thesis.bib for my bibliography and using the multibib environment and running latex via TexnicCenter Editor. But, I am unable to see the result in the end. My sample code :

```
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{Thesis, Letters}{Thesis, Letters}

\begin{document}
~\citeThesis{thesis01}
~\citeLetters{letter01}
\bibliographyThesis{thesis}
\bibliographyLetters{letters}
\end{document}
```

How can I get it to work multibib with TexnicCenter ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a way around with Texnic Center. Usually when I ask it to generate PDF, it does so, but without the citation links the first time. When I do it second time, it produces the citation links.

This is an interesting problem, probably Texnic Center has to be reconfigured. Here's the solution.

1. Based on the code above, two aux files named **Thesis.aux** and **Letters.aux** gets produced.
2. Open them in TexnicCenter and under **Build > CurrentFile > BibTex**, it should be done for each of Thesis.aux and Letters.aux separately. 
   [image]
3. Once, (2) is done, generate the PDF, you should see the result.